# Why doesn't this singleton pattern work?

Tags: c++, singleton

I have two singletons, the first one's header looks like this (I've omitted everything that is not related to the Singleton pattern):

```
#ifndef TEXTUREMANAGER_DEFINED_H
#define TEXTUREMANAGER_DEFINED_H
class FontManager;
class TextureManager
{
private:
    static TextureManager *instance;
    TextureManager();
public:
    FontManager *fontManager;
    static TextureManager* Instance();
};

#endif
```

And in the implementation, this is the Instance() method (and the initialization of the instance static member):

```
#include "FontManager.h"
TextureManager * TextureManager::instance = 0;
TextureManager* TextureManager::Instance ()
{
    if (instance==0)
        instance=new TextureManager;
    return instance;
}
```

And this is the constructor:

```
TextureManager::TextureManager()
{
    fontManager=FontManager::Instance();
}
```

The second singleton's (FontManager's) design is exactly the same, but instead of a FontManager pointer has a TextureManager pointer, and in it's constructor it initializes that pointer with TextureManager::Instance().
This should work like this: TextureManager is instanciated first (When the program starts), and in its constructor instanciates for the first time the FontManager singleton calling FontManager::Instance(). FontManager, in it's constructor, assigns its pointer to a TextureManager with TextureManager::Instance() and this method returns the TextureManager instance that already exists. Right?

But instead of that the program enters an infinite loop because (I don't know why) the Instance() methods always create a new instance. I'ts like the `if (instance==0)` always evaluated to true.

Comment: why do you need this fontManager? it is also the Singleton...so you can use it later... not in constructor of the textureManager

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you've written an infinite loop where the constructor of `TextureManager` calls the constructor of `FontManager` which then calls the constructor of `TextureManager` .... and so on.

Because the constructor has to complete before the static variables are assigned you'll end up in this loop.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I did a really silly mistake. I'll take the pointer assignments out of the constructors. I'll accept the answer as soon as i can

Comment: @XaitormanX Order of initialisation bugs with `Singleton`s. Bah! Just make one and pass it around. You don't need it to be a global with only one instance. It's just a convenience, which means you don't think carefully about your design (in this case order of initialisation).

Answer (score 0):

For singletons, you don't expose the constructor as the public interface. Instead, you have a separate, static instance-retrieval member function and a private constructor:

```
class Foo
{
    Foo() { /* ... */ }
public:
    static Foo & get()
    {
        static Foo instance;   // uses private constructor
        return instance;
    }
};
```

Alternatively to the static member you can also do your pointer trick, but then you should have a `static std::unique_ptr<Foo>` to ensure proper destruction at the program end.